# Postgresql sum all unique values from previous dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's say, for simplicity sake, I have the following table:

```
id      amount     p_id     date
------------------------------------------------
1       5          1        2020-01-01T01:00:00
2       10         1        2020-01-01T01:10:00 
3       15         2        2020-01-01T01:20:00 
4       10         3        2020-01-01T03:30:00 
5       10         4        2020-01-01T03:50:00 
6       20         1        2020-01-01T03:40:00
```

Here's a sample response I want:

```
{
 "2020-01-01T01:00:00": 25, -- this is from adding records with ids: 2 and 3
 "2020-01-01T03:00:00": 55  -- this is from adding records with ids: 3,4,5 and 6
}
```

I want to get the total (`sum(amount)`) of all unique `p_id`'s grouped by the hour.

The row chosen per `p_id` is the one with the latest `date`. So for example, the first value in the response above doesn't include `id 1` because the record with `id 2` has the same `p_id` and the `date` on that row is later.

The one tricky thing is I want to include the summation of all the `amount` per `p_id` if their `date` is before the hour presented. So for example, in the second value of the response (with key "2020-01-01T03:00:00"), even though `id 3` has a timestamp in a different hour, it's the latest for that `p_id 2` and therefore gets included in the sum for "2020-01-01T03:00:00". But the row with `id 6` overrides `id 2` with the same `p_id 1`.

In other words: always take the latest `amount` for each `p_id` so far, and compute the sum for every distinct hour found in the table.

Comment: The exact question and answer is found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270521/sum-all-unique-values-from-previous-dates

Answer (score 0):

Create a CTE that includes `row_number() over (partition by p_id, date_trunc('hour',"date") order by "date" desc) as pid_hr_seq`
Then write your query against that CTE with `where pid_hr_seq = 1`.